# Runtime error- Program terminated

Tags: java

My program terminates for some reason. Its a rock-paper-scisors simulation.
The termination takes place when I enter something in the first nextLine.
If anybody could please help.

import java.util.*;
import java.math.*;

public class RockPapperScissors {

 /**
  * @param args
  */

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
  String comp, user;
  comp=getComp();
  System.out.println("Enter rock, paper, or scissors");
  user=in.nextLine();
  winner(comp, user);


 }

 public static String getComp(){
  Random rand=new Random();
  String answer;
  int ran=rand.nextInt(3);
  if(ran==1)
   answer="rock";
  else if(ran==2)
   answer="paper";
  else 
   answer="scissors";
  return answer;}
 public static void winner(String com, String use){

  if(com=="rock" && use=="rock")
   System.out.println("Its a tie");
   else if(com=="rock" && use=="paper") 
    System.out.println("You win!");
   else if(com=="rock" && use=="scissors")
    System.out.println("Computer wins, you FAIL");
  else if(com=="paper" && use=="rock")
    System.out.println("Computer wins, you FAIL");
   else if(com=="paper" && use=="paper")
    System.out.println("Its a tie");
   else if(com=="paper" && use=="Scissors")
    System.out.println("You win!");
  else if(com=="scissors" && use=="rock")
    System.out.println("You win");
   else if(com=="scissors" && use=="paper")
    System.out.println("Computer wins, you FAIL");
   else if(com=="scissors" && use=="scissors")
    System.out.println("Its a tie");}


 }

Comment: Code formatting is your friend.

Comment: Select your code and press Ctrl-K.

Comment: I know this is a tiny program, but you might want to think about using more descriptive variable names in your code.  Instead of `use`, say `user`.  Instead of `com`, `computer`.  Again, its not a big deal in this code snippet, but once you start programming larger and larger projects, you don't want to find yourself trying to figure out what the difference between `var8` and `var9` is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For String comparison, use [`.equals()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) rather than `==`.

Answer (score 2):

Because strings are allocated to a common pool, "==" comparison will not work the way you intend it to. Use String's equals() method for comparing.